# Embed native Google Maps into a mobile application

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

We are developing a mobile application(`iOS` and `Android`) and want to embed the native Google Maps app within our custom mobile app. It is not launching the Google native Map application when the user click on something, instead displaying the native Google Maps app within the custom develop app. We know that Google provides JavaScript APIs to connect to Maps web service. But we are not able to pinch-zoom the online maps. I've seen some apps in iPhone which embeds the google maps which comes with iOS within the custom app.
Can you please suggest if it is possible to embed the native Google Maps app within a custom app?

Comment: Are you trying to create an iOS app or a web app? iOS provides Mapkit api to do what I think you are describing.

Comment: [MKMapView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android you should use MapViews and MapActivities.

More info:

[Android Doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)

The books **Android Recipes A Problem-Solution Approach** and **The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development** both have a nice chapter for solving your problem